# How to generate JSP page as PDF in client side using JavaScript with proper alignment

Tags: java, javascript

I am trying to generate the JSP page as to PDF using JavaScript. The data alignment and the data not came fully.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert HTML page ( JSP page ) as PDF using [JSPdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf).

Or you can send the content to Server side and generate PDF

Comment: i used jspdf but its not coming content of full page .it is breaking and also alignment  problem. how to overcome that.

Comment: please can u help me on that its urgent requirement

Comment: what is that you have tried and what is working and what is not working? Provide details.